# User-based location receiving notification which send in background with Capacitor/Cordova

Tags: cordova, hybrid-mobile-app, beacon, estimote, capacitor

I have an Hybrid app for both iOS and Android developed with Ionic and [Capacitor](http://capacitor.ionicframework.com).
For this App I want to send notifications if a user crosses a specific location within a few meters.
As options I figured out this could be done using Geofencing or Beacons.

As Beacons I ordered Proximity Beacons from Estimote, but I cannot find a compatible package to get this to work. It would be great to make use of the Beacons, so if someone knows a working way for this with Capacitor; please reply.

An other option is to use Geofencing. There is [this package](https://github.com/cowbell/cordova-plugin-geofence), but that one is outdated and not compiling anymore. This would be an option too, because that doesn't need a hardware beacon device to be installed somewhere.

What are my options? And is it even possible nowadays to send a background notification to a user on iOS and Android when they enter a specific location?

It is import that the Application gives a notification to the user when it enters a specific location.

Comment: Please edit your question title to English.

Comment: Sorry, auto-fill did that probably @MMM

Comment: @IwanWijaya that cannot send a push-notification if the user is in the range giventhere

Answer (score 0):

Geofencing is not trivial, there are many pitfalls that can occur, for example  how to manage the differences between handset vendors, and how to achieve a good precision. It is quite difficult to have a consistent behavior accross devices and operating systems versions. So you should look to dedicated products like [Herow](https://docs.herow.io/sdk/6.0/android/cross-platform.html) or [Radar](https://radar.io/documentation/sdk) . They may have Cordova plugins, and they have free trials.